# How to make multiple bootstrap toast align as grid?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, toast

How to make multiple **Bootstrap Toast** like side-by-side and top to top?

Link for reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/toasts/

```
<div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" style="position: relative; min-height: 200px;">
```

```
<!-- Then put toasts within -->
<div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <div class="toast-header">
    <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
    <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
    <small class="text-muted">just now</small>
    <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body">
    See? Just like this.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <div class="toast-header">
    <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
    <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
    <small class="text-muted">2 seconds ago</small>
    <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body">
    Heads up, toasts will stack automatically
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the answer is in the link for reference see `You can also get fancy with flexbox utilities to align toasts horizontally and/or vertically.`example . It tells you to use utilities flex class from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/  to build your flex grid ;)

Comment: I tried using flexbox, but it loses its format

Comment: Show what you've tried to accomplish the desired layout.

Comment: you need to combine nth-child(n) and order to reorder them as you which or use flex-column class in the case there is a known height to force container to wrap . example reordering  them : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jJWNyX

Comment: Thanks G-Cyr. Your example worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the Bootstrap docs:

> "Place toasts with custom CSS as you need them... you can also get
>   fancy with flexbox utilities to align toasts horizontally and/or
>   vertically"

So, you could put the Toasts inside an absolute positioned flexbox div. For example, here are right aligned stacked Toasts...

```
<div class="position-absolute w-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-end">
    <div class="w-25">
        <div class="toast ml-auto" role="alert" data-delay="1000" data-autohide="true">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="toast ml-auto" role="alert" data-delay="3000" data-autohide="true">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="toast ml-auto" role="alert" data-delay="5000" data-autohide="true">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are many layout options with flexbox:

Stacked vertically: https://www.codeply.com/go/3ZvZa9b8Im
Side-by-side: https://www.codeply.com/go/GFMde2ritI
3x3 grid: https://www.codeply.com/go/lj8GTFjvuK

Comment: I need them not just side-by-side, but one above other.

Comment: What do you mean? They are above each other.

Comment: There are 6 "toasts", 3 of them needs to be horizontally aligned, and the next 3 below them(like a grid). Do you get it?

Comment: Not really. It just sounds like more of the same as already explained.. you need to tweak the Toast layout as desired.

Answer (score -1):

check this out

```
<style>
#toast-container toast { width: 33%; }
</style>
<div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" style="position: relative; min-height: 200px;" id="toast-container" class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    <!-- Then put toasts within -->
    <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
            <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
            <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
            <small class="text-muted">just now</small>
            <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body">
            See? Just like this.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
            <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
            <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
            <small class="text-muted">2 seconds ago</small>
            <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body">
            Heads up, toasts will stack automatically
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
            <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
            <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
            <small class="text-muted">2 seconds ago</small>
            <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body">
            Heads up, toasts will stack automatically
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
            <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
            <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
            <small class="text-muted">2 seconds ago</small>
            <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body">
            Heads up, toasts will stack automatically
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
            <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
            <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
            <small class="text-muted">2 seconds ago</small>
            <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body">
            Heads up, toasts will stack automatically
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need them not just side-by-side, but one above other.

Comment: add the `flex-column` class too.

Comment: Do you mean to hide one with the other?

Comment: No. I need a grid like 3x3 of toats. Do you get it?

Comment: Try adding a custom css to the toast as `flex: 1 0 33%` or `width: 33%` and then add `flex flex-wrap` to the parent